# Select options on two different select box matching those of two different array values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to generate HTML by joining content from two separate arrays of equal size.  For each index in the arrays a pair of selects should be created.  The first select would have elements from the first array and the second would have elements from the second array.  In both selects, the current element should be selected.

I can create the first set of selects as demonstrated below, but I cannot figure out how to create the second set of selects.

```js
    var myArryNames = [
        "John",
        "jennifer",
        "Angel"
    ];
    
    var myArryValues = [
        "Hello World",
        "Javascript",
        "Jquery"
    ];
    
    $('#bookForm').on('click', '.mynewButton', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        $('#bookTemplate-1').removeClass('hide');
        for (var j = 1; j < myArryValues.length; j++) {
            var thisRow = $('.dropdown').last(".dropdown");
            var newid = parseInt(thisRow.attr('divid')) + 1;
            newRow = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow).
            find('select').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name', 'myDropdown[' + (newid - 1) + ']');
            }).end().
            find('option[value="' + myArryValues[j] + '"]').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }).end();
            thisRow.next('.dropdown').attr("divid", newid).attr("id", "bookTemplate-" + newid);
            //$('select[id="bookTemplate-'+newid+'"]').val(myArryValues[j]);
    
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div id="bookForm" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 button-div">
             <button type="button" class="mynewButton">Add New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group dropdown hide" id="bookTemplate-1" divid="1">
         <div class="field-row">
             <div class="col-md-2 mySelect">
                 <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown[0]">
                     <option value="Hello World">Hello World</option>
                        <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
                        <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mySelect2">
                    <select class="myNames" name="myNames[0]">
                        <option value="John">John</option>
                        <option value="Jennifer">Jennifer</option>
                        <option value="Angel">Angel</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HTML OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE BELOW

```
 <div class="col-md-2 mySelect">
    <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
      <option value="Hello World" selected="selected">Hello World</option>
      <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
      <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mySelect2">
    <select class="myNames" name="myNames">
      <option value="John" selected="selected">John</option>
      <option value="Jennifer">Jennifer</option>
      <option value="Angel">Angel</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mySelect">
    <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
      <option value="Hello World">Hello World</option>
      <option value="Javascript"  selected="selected">Javascript</option>
      <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mySelect2">
    <select class="myNames" name="myNames">
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Jennifer"  selected="selected">Jennifer</option>
      <option value="Angel">Angel</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mySelect">
      <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
      <option value="Hello World">Hello World</option>
      <option value="Javascript" >Javascript</option>
      <option value="Jquery" selected="selected">Jquery</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mySelect2">
      <select class="myNames" name="myNames">
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Jennifer" >Jennifer</option>
      <option value="Angel" selected="selected">Angel</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: How come the second drop down in your expected result is "John" "Javascript", "Jquery", makes no sense...

Comment: @KungWaz typo error

Comment: From a quick look it feels like you are only looping through myArryValues and not myArryNames. So you never select anything in myArryValues.

Comment: @KungWaz yes when I loop the second array it adds more divs at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a modification to your code that I believe does what is wanted by using the "nth-child" selector in jQuery.

Added code to do this by value instead.

```js
var myArryNames = [
        "John",
        "Jennifer",
        "Angel"
    ];
    
    var myArryValues = [
        "Hello World",
        "Javascript",
        "Jquery"
    ];
    
    $('#bookForm').on('click', '.mynewButton', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        $('#bookTemplate-1').removeClass('hide');
        var thisRow = $('.dropdown').last(".dropdown");
        // Copy the two new rows
        for (var j = 0; j < myArryValues.length; j++) {
            var row;
            // If j is non-zero, we need a new row
            if (j) {
              var newid = parseInt(thisRow.attr('divid')) + 1;
              row = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow);
              row.find('.myDropdown').attr('name', 'myDropdown[' + (newid - 1) + ']');
            }
            else {
              row = thisRow;
            }
            // Alternate 1: select the appropriate options by position.  This find will return elements from both divs, but since we don't care what the data is, just the position it works correctly
            //row.find('option:nth-child('+(j+1)+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
            // Alternate 2: Select the appropriate options by setting the value on the select itself
            //row.find('.myDropdown').val(myArryValues[j]);
            //row.find('.myNames').val(myArryNames[j]);
            // Alternate 3: Manually modify the "selected" attribute of the appropriate options.
            row.find('.myDropdown option[value="'+myArryValues[j]+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
            row.find('.myNames option[value="'+myArryNames[j]+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div id="bookForm" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 button-div">
             <button type="button" class="mynewButton">Add New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group dropdown hide" id="bookTemplate-1" divid="1">
         <div class="field-row">
             <div class="col-md-2 mySelect">
                 <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown[0]">
                     <option value="Hello World">Hello World</option>
                        <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
                        <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mySelect2">
                    <select class="myNames" name="myNames[0]">
                        <option value="John">John</option>
                        <option value="Jennifer">Jennifer</option>
                        <option value="Angel">Angel</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would love to match based on the array values not based the positioning

Comment: @YouNeverKnow No offense, but it was pretty hard even working out what you were asking in the first place.  You can just as easily select an option with a particular value: `$('option[value="'+whatever+'"]')` or you can just change the selected value on the select itself: `$('select').val(whatever)` and not mess with the `selected` attribute at all.... something like ... `thisRow.find('mySelect').val(myArryNames[j]); thisRow.find('mySelect2').val(myArryValues[j]);`

Comment: @YouNeverKnow The case makes a difference.  You have "Jennifer" in one place and "jennifer" in another.  Also ... would be handy if you put a class or an id on the actual selects instead of on the div - would be more use

Comment: @Tibrogaran, is it not possible to add selected attribute on both select drop down just as I'm doing on the first one?

Comment: @YouNeverKnow yes, but why?  jQuery is doing this for you under the covers.

Comment: @Tibrogaran, something I'm doing on the background based on the selected values, I need to pass the exact selected value to bring me another values for the last dropdown which relying on the selected second dropdown. Please help

Comment: @YouNeverKnow Dude.  The question you asked has been answered, three different ways now.  If that's not really what you wanted, you should have *put the real requirement in the question*.  Stop messing me around

Comment: @YouNeverKnow I added a version that manually sets the `selected` attribute on the options.  This was probably a complete waste of time because it's just a more convoluted way of setting it on the `select` itself.